# List Installed Program Using C/C++

Tags: dpkg, system, c++

I need to complete a short audit program written in C / C ++, which list the programs / apps installed on machines running Ubuntu, at first I could accomplish the task using "system (" dpkg -l> / tmp / appslist ") system ("nano / tmp / applist"), but the official said that can not use the "system" and should I use your own C / C ++ but generate this list of programs / apps installed.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make this program listings without using "system"?

Thank you!

Comment: can you call system inside your C/C++ program? I mean, I think you'll need to use GNU/Linux tools to get this, but you can call them using pipes, etc. inside code.

Comment: well, in fact the problem si you couldn't sue system as it won't return any feedback to your app.

I think it's not an ubuntu related question, a better place to ask could be stackoverflow.com or similars.

pipes only will need if you want to take the info at the same time the shell command is running.
if not is the case, you can simply use popen and take the return of the shell command.
some example links:
[pipes link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/116373/)
[popen link](http://www.sw-at.com/blog/2011/03/23/popen-execute-shell-command-from-cc/)

Answer (score 1):

I repeat I think it's not an ubuntu realted question, but here is my answer based in the [popen link](http://www.sw-at.com/blog/2011/03/23/popen-execute-shell-command-from-cc/) I sent you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];

    if(!(in = popen("dpkg -l > ~/appslist", "r"))){
        return 1;
    }
    pclose(in);

    if(!(in = popen("cat ~/appslist", "r"))){
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
        cout << buff;
    }
    pclose(in);

    return 0;
}
```

(I used the path ~/appslist to have permission as a normal user)

Comment: In fact, I think it's not something related to Ubuntu, just a peculiarity of my manager.

It helped a lot!